# get @ElementCollection entries with Querydsl

Tags: jpa, querydsl

I have an @Entity class which holds an @ElementCollection:

```
@Entity
public class Skill extends JpaEntity {
  @ElementCollection(targetClass = SkillName.class)
  @CollectionTable(joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "SKILL_ID"))
  private Set<SkillName> names = new HashSet<>();
...
```

Those elements are defined in a nested @Embeddable class without ID:

```
  @Embeddable
  @Immutable
  @Table(uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "NAME"))
  public static class SkillName extends ValueObject {
    private boolean selectable;
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    @Size(max = 64)
    @NotEmpty
    private String name;
...
```

I try to get some specific elements of that element-collection via Querydsl:

```
    QSkill skill = QSkill.skill;
    QSkill_SkillName skillName = QSkill_SkillName.skillName;

    List<SkillName> foundSkillNames = from(skill)
    .innerJoin(skill.names, skillName).where(...)
    .list(skillName);
```

This gives me a MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'names1_.id' in 'field list' since the resulting query looks like:

```
select names1_.id as col_0_0_ from Skill skill0_ inner join Skill_names names1_ on ...
```

which is obviously wrong since SkillName has no id

If I replace .list(skillName) with .list(skillName.name) everything works fine, but I get a list of Strings instead of a list of SkillNames.

**So the question is:**
What can I do to get a list of @Embeddables of an @ElementCollection via Querydsl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot project Embeddable instances directly, but alternatively you can use

- `Projections.bean(SkillName.class, ...)` to populate them or
- `Projections.tuple(...)` to get the skillName properties as a Tuple instance

Answer (score 3):

since you are looking for Embeddable objects inside an entity, you might navigate from the entity to the requested Embeddable (in your case "SkillName") - therefor your query should be changed to list(skill) - the entity:

```
List<Skill> list = 
    from(skill).innerJoin(skill.names, skillName).
    where(skillName.name.like(str)).
    list(skill);

for (Skill skill : list) {
  // do something with 
  Set<SkillNames> skillNames = skill.getNames();
}
```

HTH